# Как вывести дату из БД и добавить к ней один месяц?

Tags: php, дата, mysql

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, подскажите, никак не могу вывести дату и добавить к ней 1 месяци

В БД есть дата "2014-10-22".

```
$data1 = $users2[DATA1_US];
```

Вывожу я ее:

```
echo "$data1";
```

Мне нужно добавить к ней один месяц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($users2[DATA1_US]);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php

p.s. избавляйтесь от названий переменных типа $users2 и констант в качестве ключей массива, это к добру не приводит.